# change GIT LFS storage directory path

Tags: git, github, gitlab, git-lfs

When I execute:

```
$ git lfs env
```

I can see the following result:

```
git-lfs/2.12.1 (GitHub; linux amd64; go 1.14.10; git 85b28e06)
git version 2.25.1
...
LfsStorageDir=/home/luna/GITLABCI/ciprueba/.git/https:/<ownClowdserver>/remote.php/dav/files/luna/gitFiles
....
```

When "<ownClowdserver" in the original output is the server address.
This is the result of running:

```
git config lfs.storage /https:/<ownClowdserver>/remote.php/dav/files/luna/gitFiles
```

However, my intentions are to leave the LfsStorageDir like this:

```
LfsStorageDir=https:/<ownClowdserver>/remote.php/dav/files/luna/gitFiles
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `LfsStorageDir` value specifies the location on disk that Git LFS uses to store local copies of its files.  It cannot be set to an HTTP URL, and what you've done here is to specify a relative path under the `.git` directory, which is probably not what you've intended.

If you have the DAV path mounted as a FUSE file system, you can use that instead, but otherwise, unless you have a good reason, you should leave it as it is.  Do note that DAV does not provide strong POSIX file system guarantees and that using a DAV FUSE mount may or may not work, and even if it does work, it may result in missing or corrupt data.

Note that the local storage directory does not necessarily contain a full copy of all objects and therefore can't be used as a backup for your repository.  If your goal is to store a copy of your LFS objects there independent of your local repository, then you'll need to provide either a normal LFS server (and not just a DAV mount) or use a DAV FUSE file system, create a Git repository in that file system, and then push into that repository with `git lfs push --all file:///path-to-fuse-mount`.

Comment: My goal is to save the lfs objects to an external server. How do I provide a normal LFS server (and not just a DAV mount) ?

Comment: You can use the LFS test server at https://github.com/git-lfs/lfs-test-server to set up your own instance.